# A lot of buffers are being dropped

Tags: gstreamer, rtp

I'm trying to stream with RTP and the client says that there is allot of packet drops.

Server pipeline:

```
 gst-launch videotestsrc ! x264enc ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=192.168.1.16 port=5000
```

Client pipeline:

```
gst-launch udpsrc uri=udp://192.168.1.16:5000 caps="application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, sprop-parameter-sets=(string)\"Z01AFeygoP2AiAAAAwALuaygAHixbLA\\=\\,aOvssg\\=\\=\", payload=(int)96, ssrc=(uint)1645090291, clock-base=(uint)1778021115, seqnum-base=(uint)28353" ! rtph264depay ! queue ! ffdec_h264 ! autovideosink
```

I can see the video on the client, but very slowly with a lot of packet drops. The error on the client side:

```
from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAutoVideoSink:autovideosink0/GstXvImageSink:autovideosink0-actual-sink-xvimage: 
A lot of buffers are being dropped.
Additional debug info:
gstbasesink.c(2875): gst_base_sink_is_too_late (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAutoVideoSink:autovideosink0/GstXvImageSink:autovideosink0-actual-sink-xvimage:
There may be a timestamping problem, or this computer is too slow
```

If someone could tell me what am I doing wrong here, that would be great!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using "autovideosink" try "xvimagesink sync=false".

Comment: This works, but could you explain why sync should be false?